# Can I change Event Types in bulk?

Tags: civievent, batches

Can I batch change more than one event type at once? 
I want them all to be the new, same type. Do I have to go into each event configuration separately to change the event type?

Answer (score 2):

If the events are all part of a [repeating event](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/events/repeating-events/) series, then you should be able to change them by changing one, and selecting the option to change all related events.

Otherwise, I'm afraid there's no built-in way to bulk change event types.  If you know what you're doing with the API Explorer or MySQL, you can bulk change the event type on the back end - there's no real harm unless you have custom fields tied to the old event type, in which case they might show up unexpectedly on a report.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the CSV import from the Fuzion team very helpful:
https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.csvimport/blob/master/README.

At least this allows you to import events... I've not actually used it to bulk change a field in existing events, but I 'think' it might be possible.

You would need to export the events in question, and in Drupal I use Views to do that. From that export you can make a csv with the correct field(s) and data, and on import create a field map to put the new data into the correct place.